# Is there a free fingerprint reader API/SDK for java? 

Tags: java, fingerprint, biometrics

I'm looking for a totally free fingerprint reader API/SDK that I can use in my Java project.

Comment: You may have better luck doing a Google and/or [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/) search, or if you've already done this, list the most promising results and why they don't suit your need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard for such things is called BioAPI and you might have luck searching by "bioapi java". Our experience shows that different hardware vendors have their own SDKs and not all of them support BioAPI.