# Fingerprint features quantization

Tags: java, fingerprint, biometrics, quantization

I'm working on bio-metrics java project.

I extracted minutiae points from fingerprint that consists of three values (x,y,Q).

Values example:

```
 x: 274
 y: 87
angle (Q): 18
```

I need to quantize the three values to single one (double of 16 bits).

How it could be done?

Comment: What's the range of values for `x`, `y`, and `Q`? It appears that `x` and `y` can exceed 255, so, assuming they can also go as low as zero, those two alone would require more than 8 bits apiece, so you're not going to get these three values into 16 bits without giving up precision.

Comment: Rather than build this from scratch, I wonder if the hardware vendor (of the fingerprint scanner) has an API? Also, please look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/4817467/509840 or http://stackoverflow.com/a/4921793/509840 or http://stackoverflow.com/a/6550137/509840.

Comment: @rajah9 I'm using Verifinger SDK http://www.neurotechnology.com/verifinger.html

Comment: @GriffeyDog thank you for your reply, so what is the best way to compress these three values to single value?